# Automatic References for new projects in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a Visual Studio solution, for which I'm trying to keep the code fairly well separated, so I'm using quite a lot of projects.

I've got a handful of projects that use all the other projects (Unit-tests, a Bench-marker, a "Main" project). And a couple of the existing projects are going to be used *by* all the projects (core dependencies, utility projects, etc.)

The upshot is that each time I create a project, I have to give each project in the first group a reference pointing to that new project, and I have give the new project a reference pointing to each project in the second group.
I also have to add any common nuget packages I want (e.g. MoreLinq)

Is there any way to tell VS about these things and get it to do them automatically when I add a new project?

(Running VS2013 if it's relevant)

================================================

Note: It's entirely possible that the correct answer is "you're using too many projects". If you think so, thank you, but please don't feel the need to comment - that's not the question I'm interested in answering at the moment.

Comment: you could perhaps create your own nuget packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a project template new projects in your solution.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.120).aspx for more details.